# Is there a way to get direct binding to a "number" input field that watches the arrows?

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, input, range

I have a set of inputs and for each value that I'm inputting I have a "range" slider and a "number" input. I have a little bit of JS that is called by both the slider and the number field using the onchange="send(input_id, input_kind, this.value)" attribute for each input.
If the slider moved I update the number and if the number changed I update the slider.

This is fine for the slider as as soon as one moves it, the number starts tracking along. When one adjusts the number with the little up/down arrows or types numbers the slider does not update. The JS is not called until another field is selected, i.e.. the input loses focus then it passes it's data to me bind{k, d, v} function.

HTML:

```
            <div class="number-pair">
                <sub-title>X-Position</sub-title><br />
                <input id="/layout/1/slider" class="slider" type="range" value="0" min="-1" max="1" step="0.01" onchange="bind('/layout/1', 'slider', parseFloat(this.value))" />
                <input id="/layout/1/number" class="number-box" type="number" value="0" min="-1" max="1" step="0.01" onchange="bind('/layout/1', 'number', parseFloat(this.value))" /><br />    
            </div>
```

JS:

```
        function bind(id, control, v)
        { 
            if (control=="slider")
            {
            if (console) console.log("It's a slider");
                e = document.getElementById("/layout/1/number");
                if (e)
                {
                    e.value = v;
                }
            } else if (control=="number")
            {
            if (console) console.log("It's a float");                   
                e = document.getElementById("/layout/1/slider");
                if (e)
                {
                    e.value = v;
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I get a more responsive binding for using number arrows?

N.B. I'm not just binding the two inputs to each other but to on-screen effects elsewhere so move responsive binding is desirable in that context not just the slider which I could live with.
Also I'm using literals to find update the paired value in my JS but literals will be replaced with a dynamic expression so I can bind a whole range of slider/text number input pairs.

Comment: Is this a really long winded way of asking why doesn't the change event fire when the user types into an input of `type="number"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the input fields, bind to the `onkeypress`, rather than the `onchange` event, because the `onchange` event isn't called until the control loses focus.  To trap arrow presses, bind to the `onclick` event.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using onkeypress and onclick:

```
            <div class="number-pair">
<br />
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I can do it inside the CSS class .number.pair {}?

Answer (score 1):

`onchange` only trigger the event, when the element loses focus.

To more responsive feedback you should use:

`onmousedown` `onmouseup` events on slider, you can also use `onmousemove` to "realtime" effect.
`onkeypress` on the text field.

Comment: Can I assign more than one event type at one time, e.g. <input… onclick=onkeypress="bind(id, kind, this.value) />"?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this way, but I rather attach events by javascript. Is not a good practice using javascript inline.

Comment: Yes right that was going to be my next question for refactoring my code — making my first web app so taking baby steps. Shall I ask a new question up above about that or a completely new thread?

Comment: I think your question is not related to the above code itself, so you should open a new thread, if it has not been answered previously. Just make sure you always search before asking a question, because a lot already have good answers, and of course you do not have to wait for the answers `;)`

Comment: Can you suggest the best tokens for me to search for ways to dynamically assign JS code to (say) input controls? This is all totally new for me and don't know the way HTML/CSS/JS rolls!

Comment: Well you said the way I'm doing my JS inline is not good practice. And to keep the code DRY it would be nice if I could iterate thru a bunch of sliders and number-box-inputs and bind them to each other using there overlapping ids (/slider/[0-22] binds to /number-box/[0-22]) using onclick and other predefined methods. Also need to bind the whole lot to a structure which sends them all across the interwebs with a web-socket call which I have working already but only on a per-control basis.

Comment: Oh, got it. I would use `addEventListenner` to attach events to elements, but I use a function to deal with IE issues. And I also use a class to add events to multiples elements.